# Java Struts not working on RedHat server (attribute scope must be declared for element type form-bean)

Tags: java, spring, scope, attributes, struts-1

So here's the thing, we have a legacy Java application using struts 1.2 currently deployed on a solaris platform(using tomcat 5). We have a migration activity which we need to transfer this application to a RedHat server. All of the setup are the same including configs and libraries(we literally just copied the whole folder from solaris to redhat) . But currently we are receiving this error "attribute scope must be declared for element type form-bean" which is weird since we are not encountering this on the old server.

the application's form bean looks like this>>

```
 <form-beans>
       <form-bean name ="groupformbean" type="cetreon.portal.GroupFormBean" scope="request">
       </form-bean>

       <form-bean name ="accountMapping" type="com.db.formbeans.AccountMappingBean"  scope="request">
       </form-bean> 

       <form-bean name ="staticdataview" type="com.db.formbeans.StaticDataForBean"  scope="request">
       </form-bean>
 </form-beans>
```

(there are a lot of form beans so im gonna give these 3 as example)

I've tried searching everywhere with no luck. I've tried updating the DTDs and libraries, but still the issues persists.